# 1 EIN doing business under multiple business names

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business

I have 2 small business LLC's registered in Wisconsin, each with their own EIN.  Call them Company A LLC and Company B LLC.  I'm converting Company A LLC into an S Corp.  Company B LLC will have it's sales run under Company A LLC, and cease operating as a separate entity.  I plan on calling Company B LLC, Company B Shop.

I need to get a new checking account in the name of Company B Shop but my bank is saying that I need to contact the IRS and get a new SS-4 Form listing Company B Shop with Company A LLC's EIN.  I tried contacting the IRS and wasn't able to get through.  My accountant said I just need to setup a DBA through the state of Wisconsin.  Can anyone point me in the right direction here?  Thanks in advance and I know it's confusing!

Comment: Please explain the term `DBA`.

Comment: DBA = doing business as. A public declaration that links a fictitious business name with the legal name of the person who owns it.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing a lot of things here.

> Company B LLC will have it's sales run under Company A LLC, and cease operating as a separate entity

These two are contradicting each other. If B LLC ceases to exist - it is not going to have it's sales run under A LLC, since there will be no sales to run for a non-existent company.

What happens is that you merge B LLC into A LLC, and then convert A LLC into S Corp. So you're cancelling the EIN for B LLC, you're cancelling the EIN for A LLC - because both entities cease to exist. You then create a EIN for A Corp, which is the converted A LLC, and you create a DBA where `A Corp DBA B Shop`. You then go to the bank and open the account for `A Corp DBA B Shop` with the EIN you just created for A Corp.

Get a better accountant. Before you convert to S-Corp.

Comment: My account is keeping Company A LLC as the name of the S Corp with the same EIN that Company A LLC had/has.

Comment: @Tom you cannot do that. You cannot change entity and keep the same EIN, you have to re-issue a new EIN.